# React Native tests failing: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fs' of undefined"

Tags: react-native, jestjs

When I run `npm test`:

```
➜  mobile git:(develop) ✗ npm test
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/index.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'fs' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-cached-image/utils/fsUtils.js:9:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-cached-image/ImageCacheManager.js:5:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-cached-image/CachedImage.js:13:23)
```

I see it's related to `react-native-cached-image` dependency on `fs`.
Do I have to mock fs somehow? I tried couple of things but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mocking components using fs**

Instead of mocking fs I would recommend you to mock *react-native-image-cache* if possible because fs is used by one of the dependencies of that package. You can see [the line listed in you're error](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image/blob/master/utils/fsUtils.js#L9).

You can just mock react-native-image-cache like the following:

```
jest.mock('react-native-img-cache', () => {
  return {
    DocumentDir: () => {},
    ImageCache: {
      get: {
        clear: () => {}
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

In the same matter it should be possible to mock *react-native-fetch-blob* which is using fs and causing the error. The properties on the return statement depend on the methods and properties that are used by image-cache lib. Probably you don't need as much as listed below but now you know that there could be more than fs.

```
jest.mock('react-native-fetch-blob', () => {
  return {
    DocumentDir: () => {},
    fetch: () => {},
    base64: () => {},
    android: () => {},
    ios: () => {},
    config: () => {},
    session: () => {},
    fs: {
      dirs: {
        MainBundleDir: () => {},
        CacheDir: () => {},
        DocumentDir: () => {},
      },
    },
    wrap: () => {},
    polyfill: () => {},
    JSONStream: () => {}
  }
})
```

---

**Mocking fs**

In case you want/need to mock fs specifically, you could do the following:

1. Study the tests used by the library [react-native-cached-image](https://github.com/kfiroo/react-native-cached-image/tree/master/__tests__)
2. Use one of the npm packages for mocking fs: [mock-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-fs), [jest-plugin-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-plugin-fs) or [fake-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fake-fs)
3. Do it yourself

Sometimes it's even possible to do something like that:

```
fs = require("fs")
fs.readFile = function (filename, cb) {
  cb(null, new Buffer("fake contents");
};
// etc
```

But keep in mind that fs is used somewhere in an dependent package. In that case I'm not sure if the code works properly and this is why I put the other options at the top.